# RStudio cannot reach .Rhistory on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rstudio

I was working with markdown file on RStudio. I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I produce html files using knitr. I decided to clean my enviroment and added rm and gc commands at the end.
Now here is a message in my console window:

```
Error attempting to read history from ~/.Rhistory: permission denied (is the .Rhistory file owned by root?)
```

What it means? Is it bad for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the best traditions of stackoverflow I reply to my own question! The problem occurred because when I first started R, I did it as su:

```
sudo R
```

so I can load a lot of useful libraries in /usr/lib/R/site-library and not in my account. As result  .Rhistory became su file. It is possible for RStudio to see it if it is started as

```
sudo rstudio
```

and then all is fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are right - the first time you ran it, you were in sudo mode, and the .Rhistory file was created with *root* as the owner. Running RStudio as root would remove the symptom, but is not ideal. To be able to run it as a regular user, simply change the owner of the .Rhistory file:

```
sudo chown -c <user_name> .Rhistory
```

Comment: @Mathemilda Please mark this as the solution by checking the green arrow

Comment: It not was not an answer, it was a confirmation of my solution. After I figured out what happened, then there are a number of ways to fix the problem. In Linux I can click on a file and change its permissions. I prefer mine.